# How to find the best match between 2 keywords lists

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I'm making an ad network for my specific needs:

- User picks keywords and add them to an article
- Advertiser picks keywords and add them to his ad

When a viewer goes into the User's article, what I need to find is the ad with the highest amount of matching keywords to that specific article (or any ad if no matching keywords)

User keyword table example:

```
ArticleID | keyword
1         | funny
1         | memes
1         | lol
2         | boring
```

Advertiser keyword table example

```
AdId      | keyword
1         | funny
1         | lol
2         | funny
2         | food
3         | kids
```

So if a viewer will go into the article with id=1, the resulting ad will be
the ad with id=1, because it has matched both "funny" and "lol", a more detailed result:

```
Result:
AdId      | count
1         | 2
2         | 1
3         | 0
```

How can I build a query to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could join on the keywords and count the results:

```
SELECT   AdId, COUNT(*)
FROM     ad_keywords a
JOIN     user_keywords u ON a.keyword = u.keyword
WHERE    article_id = 1
GROUP BY AdId
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: And select only the first record

Comment: @KristjanKica Oops, forgot a `limit` clause - see my edited answer

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you, didn't realize it could be that simple...

Comment: @mureinik didnt downvote. I thought you may had forgotten. Looks good now.